# Exporting Twilio Data

Tags: csv, twilio, data-cleaning, sos

I want to know how can I export the data I collect through Twilio Api. I want to know if there is an easy way to export the data to csv in the most "clean" way as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using the Twilio CLI.

You can find more information here.

[Twilio CLI Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/quickstart)

Some example CLI syntax to get you started:

`twilio api:core:messages:list --help`

`twilio api:core:calls:list --help`